# cant get layout inflater to work

Tags: android, android-layout

Having trouble getting layout inflater to work - wondering if someone get shed some light on why the text view is not working..

this is main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="#A9BCF5"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:weightSum="1">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="639dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="@drawable/retreatgoddess"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:layout_weight="0.80" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/affirmation"
    android:layout_weight="0.23"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#1728ff"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:typeface="sans"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

this is the method

```
 public void fillTextView(Context context, int layoutId, int resId, String text)
 {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutId, null);
    TextView textElement = (TextView) view.findViewById(resId);
    textElement.setText(text);

 }
```

i am calling it via

```
fillTextView(context, R.layout.main, R.id.affirmation, "i love you");
```

i am getting the background but no text

Comment: where do you add the view to the activity

Comment: you are using an EditText object and in the inflater you call TextView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using layout weight, you should set `android:layout_height` to `0px` on both `imageView` and `affirmation`. Then the layout will be calculated properly.

Also, the total weight in your case is 1.03, yet you set the sum to 1.0. Change the sum or one of the layout weights.